# What is the difference between Halt and Shutdown commands?

Tags: command-line, shutdown

What is the difference between the `halt` and `shutdown` commands?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Generally, one uses the [`shutdown` command](http://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown). It allows a time delay and warning message before shutdown or reboot, which is important for system administration of multiuser shell servers; it can provide the users with advance notice of the downtime.

As such, the shutdown command has to be used like this to halt/switch off the computer immediately (on Linux and FreeBSD at least):

```
shutdown -h now
```

Or to reboot it with a custom, 30 minute advance warning:

```
shutdown -r +30 "Planned software upgrades"
```

After the delay, `shutdown` tells [`init`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/init) to change to runlevel 0 (halt) or 6 (reboot). (Note that omitting `-h` or `-r` will cause the system to go into single-user mode (runlevel 1), which kills most system processes but does not actually halt the system; it still allows the administrator to remain logged in as root.)

Once system processes have been killed and filesystems have been unmounted, the system halts/powers off or reboots automatically. This is done using the [`halt` or `reboot` command](http://linux.die.net/man/8/halt), which syncs changes to disks and then performs the actual halt/power off or reboot.

On Linux, if `halt` or `reboot` is run when the system has not already started the shutdown process, it will invoke the `shutdown` command automatically rather than directly performing its intended action. However, [on systems such as FreeBSD](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=8&topic=halt), these commands first log the action in [`wtmp`](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=5&topic=wtmp) and then will *immediately* perform the halt/reboot themselves, without first killing processes or unmounting filesystems.

Comment: … but now out of date.  On systemd Linux operating systems, these commands exist (in the words of the systemd doco) "for compatibility only".  There are not separate `halt`, `reboot`, and `shutdown` programs that invoke one another.  There's one single program, with a lot of command-line parsers that funnel into one code path internally.  Nor are there run levels.  Nor does shutdown go into a single user mode.  Indeed, single user mode itself has been renamed.  For details, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132 .

Comment: if I use only `shutdown now` it's equivalent to `telinit 1` ? are you sure? I've tested it on debian but it will halt.

Answer (score 87):

## The past

In the 1980s, the BSDs had `halt`, `reboot`, and `shutdown`.  System 5 UNIX had a BSD compatibility toolset.  But natively it had its own, different, `shutdown` command; and didn't have `halt` or `reboot` at all.  (Some System 5 variants had things like SCO XENIX's `haltsys`.)

The BSD `halt` and `reboot` commands were low-level, drastic, and immediate.  The *considerate* way to shut down a BSD system was the `shutdown` command, which did all of the things that one expects to happen: `wall` messages to users, services gracefully killed, log entries written, logins disabled, and so forth.

Whilst the BSDs were largely where the received wisdom originated that "`shutdown` execs `halt`/`reboot`", and that the latter were to be used with care; it was the System 5 world where people learned the contrary habit that `halt`/`reboot` were just handy shorthands and nothing more: `/usr/ucb/halt`, from the "BSD Compatibility Package", was no different in effect to `shutdown -h`.  They both ended up doing `init 0`.

### Further reading

- [`halt`](http://modman.unixdev.net/?sektion=8&page=halt&manpath=4.2BSD).  1982-05-11.  4.2BSD manual.
- [`haltsys`](http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/man/html.ADM/haltsys.ADM.html).  2005-06-03.  SCO OpenServer manual.
- AT&T (1990).  [*UNIX System 5 Release 4: BSD/XENIX Compatibility Guide*](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/att/unix/System_V_Release_4/0-13-933664-8_Unix_System_V_Rel4_BSD_XENIX_Compatibility_Guide_1990.pdf).  Prentice Hall.
- AT&T (1990).  [*UNIX System 5 Release 4: System Admninistrators' Guide*](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/att/unix/System_V_Release_4/0-13-947086-7_Unix_System_V_Rel4_System_Administrators_Guide_1990.pdf).  Prentice Hall.

## Today

Nowadays, we have a range of possible system management toolsets.  The BSDs still have their toolset, albeit purged of any possible AT&Tisms in the 1990s.  Miquel van Smoorenburg in 1992 (re-)wrote a Linux `init`+`rc`, and their associated tools, which people now refer to as "System 5 init", even though it isn't actually the software from UNIX System 5 (and isn't just `init`).  There are also [systemd](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/), [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), and [nosh](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/), each of which have *their own implementations* of `halt`, `reboot`, `fasthalt`, `fastboot`, and so forth.

The toolsets have also grown and changed.  There's now a `poweroff` command, not present in 1980s operating systems because the Central Processing Units on most contemporary machines had no way of controlling their power supplies.  Linux toolsets in particular have aquired the BSD commands; but like the BSD compatibility tools on UNIX System 5, they aren't exact workalikes and things have been largely flattened.

This flattening has brought us to the point where `halt` and `shutdown` are *mostly* the same.  But the exact details vary from toolset to toolset, and the mechanics of each toolset are all slightly different.

It has also brought us to the slightly embarrassing position where this command set has become so festooned with compatibility options that it now allows people to give computers self-contradictory instructions like `reboot --halt` and `poweroff --reboot`, as I noted in the manual page for the nosh `halt`, `fasthalt`, `reboot`, `fastboot`, and `poweroff` commands. ☺

### The systemd toolset

`halt`, `reboot`, `poweroff`, `telinit`, and `shutdown` are *all one program*.  It's actually systemd's own `systemctl` program.  It has several command line parsers for the various command line syntaxes of those commands, as well as its own, but after that largely funnels into one code path internally.  There's no difference between using `halt` and its command options to trigger an action and using `shutdown` and its command options to trigger the same action.

systemd does not consider *rescue mode* (which is what the systemd people have renamed *single user mode*) to be a shut down system state, and it is not reachable with any of these commands.  Option-less `shutdown now` is the same as `poweroff`.

#### Further reading:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132 .

### The BSDs

The BSDs largely retain their 1980s semantics.  `halt` and `shutdown` are thus very much *not* equivalent in their toolsets.  `halt` and `reboot` are one single program; and are still low level, immediate, and drastic.  Whereas `shutdown` and `poweroff`, also one single program, do all of the considerate things like scheduled shutdown, writing `wall` messages, logging actions, disabling login, and so forth.

In the BSD toolsets, `shutdown`/`poweroff` traditionally ended up invoking `halt`/`reboot` to enact the final system state change.  The (often nowadays incorrect) received wisdom that "`shutdown` execs `halt`/`reboot`" in fact still holds on NetBSD and OpenBSD.  But on FreeBSD/TrueOS/DragonFlyBSD it is only the case if the `-o` option is used.  On these BSDs, *both* of these programs *normally* enact the final system state change by sending various signals (`INT`, `USR1`, and `USR2`) to process #1.  `init` does *all* system state management on on these systems.

On all of them, option-less `shutdown now` is not equivalent to any of `halt`, `reboot`, or `poweroff`.  It transitions to the BSD *single user mode*, from which one can transition *back* to *multi-user mode*.

#### Further reading:

- [`shutdown`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?shutdown+8).  *System Manager's Manual*.  NetBSD Manual pages. 2011-11-04.
- [`reboot`, `halt`](http://man.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/halt.8).  OpenBSD Manual pages.  2016-09-03.
- [`shutdown`](https://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=shutdown).  FreeBSD Manual pages.  2016-09-21.
- [`reboot`, `halt`, `fastboot`, `fasthalt`](https://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=halt).  FreeBSD Manual pages.  2017-03-19.
- [`shutdown`](http://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/cgi/web-man?command=shutdown).  *System Manager's Manual*.  DragonFlyBSD Manual pages.  2016-09-29.
- [`reboot`, `halt`, `fastboot`, `fasthalt`](http://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/cgi/web-man?command=halt).  *System Manager's Manual*.  DragonFlyBSD Manual pages.  2016-09-29.

### The nosh toolset

In the nosh system management toolset, `halt`, `fasthalt`, `poweroff`, `fastpoweroff`, `reboot`, and `fastboot` are all one program.  It's a backwards compatibility shim that normally simply chains to `shutdown`, the *opposite* of received wisdom.  The `--force` option makes it chain to `system-control` instead.

So there's no difference (absent `--force`) between the `halt` command and the `shutdown` command (with the equivalent option) in this toolset, as this set of "BSD/System 5 compatibility" commands is simply a thin shim layer over the top of `shutdown`.

#### Further reading:

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`shutdown`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/shutdown.xml).  nosh toolset manual pages.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`telinit, init, reboot, halt, haltsys, powercycle, poweroff, … fastboot, fasthalt, fastpowercycle, fastpoweroff, …`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/telinit.xml)  nosh toolset manual pages.  Softwares.

### The upstart toolset

Like with nosh, in the upstart system management toolset the opposite of received BSD wisdom applies.  `halt`, `reboot`, and `poweroff` are all one program, that normally chains to `shutdown`; unless the `--force` option is used, which makes it make the `reboot()` system call itself.

So, again, there's no difference (absent `--force`) between the `halt` command and and `shutdown` command (with the equivalent option) in this toolset.  Also again, option-less `shutdown now` (which none of `halt`, `reboot`, or `poweroff` can end up invoking as they all set options) brings the system into *single user mode* rather than shutting it down.

#### Further reading:

- Scott James Remnant.  [`shutdown`(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/shutdown.8.html).  Ubuntu manual pages.
- Scott James Remnant.  [`reboot`(8), `halt`(8), `poweroff`(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/reboot.8.html).  Ubuntu manual pages.

### The Linux System 5 `init`+`rc` toolset

Again, in this toolset the opposite of received BSD wisdom applies and `halt` and `reboot` simply chain to `shutdown` — unless the system is already in the poweroff or halt "run-levels", in which case these commands actually enact the final system state change.  `shutdown` in its turn chains to `init`.

So, again, there's no difference (unless the system is *already* largely shut down) between `halt` and `shutdown` because the former just invokes the latter.  And yes, again, option-less `shutdown now` (which none of `halt`, `reboot`, or `poweroff` can end up invoking as they all set options) brings the system into *single user mode* rather than shutting it down.

Comment: How do you gracefully shutdown or restart an Ubuntu/systemd server? Does shutdown vs poweroff matter? In the case when I want to shutdown/poweroff now or in the case where I want to let it wait a minute first.

Answer (score 12):

I suspect this is somewhat dependant on which version of UNIX/Linux you are using. On Centos (and I expec other modern Linux) halt calls shutdown (providing you're not at [runlevel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel) 0 or 6) so your system will be shutdown cleanly. On Solaris 10 halt is more brutal, it just flushes the disk caches and powers off the system - no attempt is made to run any scripts or shutdown [smf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Management_Facility) facilities.

Answer (score 3):

Cheat sheet:

```
halt           # halts the system but does not power off the computer
halt -p        # halts + power off computer
shutdown now   # halts + power off computer
shutdown       # halts + power off computer after 1 minute
poweroff       # halts + power off computer
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who use AWS EC2: on AWS `shutdown` **stops** an instance, when `halt` **terminates** it.

Comment: What's the difference between _stop_ and _terminate_?

Comment: That's completely different topic, being offtop here, that's why I didn't mention it. But you can take a look on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html#lifecycle-differences

Comment: So in your answer, you're saying that _stop_ does what is says, and stops the instance, whereas _halt_ (or in your alternative terminology, _terminate_) stops the instance and deletes it.

Comment: Yes. But that's AWS-specific.

Comment: Ah. I see. The OP hasn't provided context. You have. Thanks.

Comment: this doesn't seem right, please see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingInstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior

Comment: By default, when you initiate a shutdown from an Amazon EBS-backed instance (using a command such as shutdown or poweroff), the instance stops (Note that halt does not issue a poweroff command and, if used, the instance will not terminate; instead, it will place the CPU into HLT and the instance will remain running). You can change this behavior using the InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior attribute for the instance so that it terminates instead. You can update this attribute while the instance is running or stopped.

Answer (score 1):

In linux, "halt" and "reboot" are aliases of the shutdown command -- `shutdown -h` and `shutdown -r` respectively. Bareword shutdown generally assumes -h.

Comment: They're not `aliases` in the sense of shell aliases, but yes, `halt` basically just calls `shutdown -h` and `reboot` runs `shutdown -r`.  Note that if you pass the `-f` (force) option to `halt` or `reboot`, `shutdown` is **not** called.

Comment: Actually, although it is still wrong, on systemd operating systems Shadur's description here is closer to the truth than Mikel's correction is.  There's no "A just calls B". They are all alternative ways of invoking _one single program_, as explained in more detail at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132 .

Comment: @JdeBP Back when I wrote this systemd was out for less than a year and I'd never even heard of it, mind. :)

Comment: @JdeBP I'd equate them to, say, the `sendmail` command at this point -- Like with MTAs, it doesn't actually matter what init system you use because all of them will recognize both `shutdown` and `halt` as such.

Comment: Actually, it does matter; because there are subtle, and indeed unsubtle, differences between toolsets.  Ironically, that is also the case with the `sendmail` command.  It's like the `sendmail` command, but not in the way that you think.