# Why do we need the reboot function in different binaries?

Tags: linux, history, shutdown

Why do we need the reboot function in different binaries?

```
shutdown -r
```

and

```
reboot
```

Or do they differ in something?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/what-is-the-difference-between-halt-and-shutdown-commands for the distinction - the commands can behave differently depending on operating system (but generally do the same thing in Linux).

Comment: As noted below and explained in detail at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132 , the premise of this question is false on systemd Linux operating systems.  These are _not_ different binaries on such systems.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We don't necessarily need them both, but we have them both because of the history of Unix, and its multiplicity of versions.

From their respective man pages:

- The shutdown utility appeared in 4.0BSD.
- A reboot utility appeared in Version 6 AT&T UNIX.

shutdown is more general-purpose, and more powerful, while reboot is friendlier and easier to remember.

shutdown allows you to specify a temporal argument (to restart in 5 minutes, for instance) and allows you to do many things besides reboot, including:

- you can just kick off users and not actually shutdown
- you can put the system to sleep instead of shutting down
- you can simply shutdown without rebooting (like the halt command)
- you can include a custom warning message for users on the system

However, if you just want to reboot the system now, it's easier to type `reboot` than `shutdown -r now`.

Comment: Fun fact: Some versions of `shutdown` use now as default. Do not try to get help for shutdown with `shutdown -h` ever, especially not on a server somewhere in a datacenter.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what iconoclast wrote, there's an important distinction between the two programs: `shutdown` is in `/sbin`, while `reboot` is in `/usr/bin`.

Why does this matter, you ask? I will tell you.

Things under `/usr` are those that do not have to be available until the system is booted up far enough that the system is minimally functional. Top-level directories that are traditionally never mounted on separate filesystems — `/bin`, `/etc`, `/sbin`, etc. — are expected to be available while the system is reaching this minimally useful state. There are various implications of this design; for instance, it is bad style to write the "stop" clause of a SysV init script that uses programs in `/usr/bin` if there is an alternative in `/bin` or `/sbin`.

`shutdown` is the key utility, the one always available. `reboot` is a convenience utility only.

Comment: `reboot` is in `/sbin` in Debian (with SysVinit) and Ubuntu (with upstart).

Comment: Okay, so meta-answer: know thy system. :) I use CentOS most often.

Comment: Same for Arch (systemd), both in /sbin

Comment: Indeed, on systemd Linux operating systems _neither_ is the key utility, as with systemd _all_ of these commands are (as the systemd doco has it) "compatibility" commands.  Indeed, the premise of the question is false.  They _are not_ in different binaries.  For details, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132 .

Answer (score 6):

The two commands do something different, however they can end up calling each other, which is why they *seem* to do the same thing!

`reboot` will invoke the kernel to actually trigger a hardware reboot. However, it will only do this if the system is ready for shutdown - all daemons and user processes should be stopped, file systems unmounted, etc. So it checks the system runlevel, and if it's not 0 or 6, then it will actually invoke the `shutdown` command for you.

`shutdown` causes the system runlevel to be changed. The runlevel change (to 0 for halt or 6 for reboot) runs lots of scripts in /etc/rc0.d or rc6.d that shut down daemons, unmount filesystems, etc. Finally these scripts invoke `halt` or `reboot` - this time the system is in the correct runlevel and they instruct the kernel to reboot (or halt).