# What is the difference between these commands for bringing down a Linux server?

Tags: rhel, shutdown

Reading ["What is the difference between Halt and Shutdown commands?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/what-is-the-difference-between-halt-and-shutdown-commands) , I generally have an idea what does the command shutdown does, with or without -h/-r options.

> The "halt" command performs power off of the system to run-level 0 of
>   the system.
>
> The "shutdown" command performs a power off of the system to run-level
>   1 without -h or -r command.

What about the command "poweroff" does it goes into run-level 0 or 1 ? 
Is this the only main difference between these three commands?

Comment: Related http://askubuntu.com/q/578144/216503

Comment: This is some of the things that differ significantly for e.g. Solaris and FreeBSD. (There they usually (almost) immediately halt / shutdown the server, without changing runlevels to shut down stuff first)

Answer (score 168, accepted):

### And now, the systemd answer.

You're using, per the tag on your question, Red Hat Enterprise Linux.  Since version 7, that has used systemd.  None of the other answers are correct for the world of systemd; nor even are some of the assumptions in your question.

- [Forget about runlevels](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394238/5132); they exist, but only as compatibility shims.  The systemd documentation states that the concept is "obsolete".  If you're starting to learn this stuff on a systemd operating system, don't start there.
- Forget about the manual page that marcelm quoted; it's not from the right toolset at all, and is a description of another toolset's command, incorrect for systemd's.  It's the one for the `halt` command from the van Smoorenburg "System 5" `init` utilities.
- Ignore the statements that `/sbin/halt` is a symbolic link to `/sbin/reboot`; that's not true with systemd.  There is no separate `reboot` program at all.
- Ignore the statements that `halt` or `reboot` invoke a `shutdown` program with command-line arguments; they are also not true with systemd.  There is no separate `shutdown` program at all.

Every system management toolset has its version of these utilities.  systemd, upstart, [nosh](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh.html), van Smoorenburg `init`, and BSD `init` all have their own `halt`, `poweroff`, and so forth.  On each their mechanics are slightly different.  So are their manual pages.

In the systemd toolset [`halt`,`poweroff`,`reboot`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/halt.html), [`telinit`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/telinit.html), and [`shutdown`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/shutdown.html) are *all* symbolic links to `/bin/systemctl`.  They are *all* backwards compatibility shims, that are simply shorthands for invoking systemd's primary command-line interface: `systemctl`.  They all map to (and in fact are) that same *single* program.  (By convention, the shell tells it which name it has been invoked by.)

### targets, not runlevels

Most of those commands are shorthands for telling systemd, using `systemctl`, to *isolate* a particular *target*.  Isolation is explained in the `systemctl` manual page (q.v.), but can be, for the purposes of this answer, thought of as starting a target and stopping any others.  The standard targets used in systemd are listed on the `systemd.special`(8) manual page.

The diagrams on the `bootup`(7) manual page in the systemd toolset, in particular the last one, show that there are three "final" targets that are relevant here:

- `halt.target` — Once the system has reached the state of fully isolating this target, it will have called the `reboot(RB_HALT_SYSTEM)` system call.  The kernel will have attempted to enter a ROM monitor program, or simply halted the CPU (using whatever mechanism is appropriate for doing so).
- `reboot.target` — Once the system has reached the state of fully isolating this target, it will have called the `reboot(RB_AUTOBOOT)` system call (or the equivalent with the magic command line).  The kernel will have attempted to trigger a reboot.
- `poweroff.target` — Once the system has reached the state of fully isolating this target, it will have called the `reboot(RB_POWER_OFF)` system call.  The kernel will have attempted to remove power from the system, if possible.

*These* are the things that you should be thinking about as the final system states, not run levels.  Notice from the diagram that the systemd target system itself encodes things that are, in other systems, implicit rather than explicit: such as the notion that each of these final targets encompasses the `shutdown.target` target, so that one describes services that must be stopped before shutdown by having them *conflict with* the `shutdown.target` target.

`systemctl` tries to send requests to [`systemd-logind`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-logind.service.html) when the calling user is not the superuser.  It also passes delayed shutdowns over to [`systemd-shutdownd`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-shutdownd.service.html).  And some shorthands trigger `wall` notifications.  Those complexities aside, which would make this answer several times longer, assuming that you are currently the superuser and not requesting a scheduled action:

- `systemctl isolate halt.target` has the shorthands:

  - `shutdown -H now`
  - `systemctl halt`
  - plain unadorned `halt`
- `systemctl isolate reboot.target` has the shorthands:

  - `shutdown -r now`
  - `telinit 6`
  - `systemctl reboot`
  - plain unadorned `reboot`
- `systemctl isolate poweroff.target` has the shorthands:

  - `shutdown -P now`
  - `telinit 0`
  - `shutdown now`
  - `systemctl poweroff`
  - plain unadorned `poweroff`
- `systemctl isolate rescue.target` has the shorthands:

  - `telinit 1`
  - `systemctl rescue`
- `systemctl isolate multi-user.target` has the shorthands:

  - `telinit 2`
  - `telinit 3`
  - `telinit 4`
- `systemctl isolate graphical.target` has the shorthand:

  - `telinit 5`

After parsing the various differing command-line syntaxes, these all eventually end up in the same code paths inside the `systemctl` program.

Notes:

- The traditional behaviour of option-less `shutdown now` has been to switch to *single-user mode*.  This is not the case with systemd.  `rescue.target` — single-user mode being renamed *rescue mode* in systemd — is not reachable with the `shutdown` command.
- `telinit` *really does* wholly ignore all of those `runlevelN.target` and `default.target` symbolic links in the filesystem that the manual pages describe.  The aforegiven mappings are hardwired into the `systemctl` program, in a table.
- systemd has no notion of a *current run level*.  The operation of these commands is not conditional upon any "if you are in run-level *N*".
- The `--force` option to the `halt`, `reboot`, and `poweroff` commands is the same as saying `--force --force` to the `systemctl halt`, `systemctl reboot`, and `systemctl poweroff` commands.  This makes `systemctl` try to call `reboot()` directly.  Normally it just tries to isolate targets.
- `telinit` is not the same as `init`.  They are different programs in the systemd world, the latter being another name for the `systemd` program, not for the `systemctl` program.  The `systemd` program is not necessarily compiled with any van Smoorenburg compatibility at all, and on some systemd operating systems complains about being invoked incorrectly if one attempts `init N`.

### Further reading

- [Are there any good reasons for halting system without cutting power?](https://superuser.com/questions/900109/)
- [Why does `init 0` result in "Excess Arguments" on Arch install?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389289/)
- Stephen Wadeley (2014).  ["8. Managing Services with systemd"](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/chap-Managing_Services_with_systemd.html) *Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 System Administrators' Guide*.  Red Hat.
- Lennart Poettering (2013-10-07).  [`systemctl`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html). systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.
- Lennart Poettering (2013-10-07).  [`systemd.special`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html). systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.
- Lennart Poettering (2013-10-07).  [`bootup`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html). systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018).  [`init`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/init.html). *nosh Guide*. Softwares.

Comment: This is very much generic for most modern Linux systems so for instance answers https://wiert.me/2012/12/30/opensuse-12-x-a-plain-halt-will-not-shutdown-the-system-properly/ After all these years wondering, I finally understand what's going on and why.

Comment: `systemctl reboot` should be equivalent to `systemctl start reboot.target --job-mode=replace-irreversible`.  Using any other job mode is less robust.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381739/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-systemctl-start-reboot-target-and-sy

Comment: I read your entire reponse, and absorbed what I could.  One question remains, the same one i came here for, is `systemctl reboot` the "safe" way to reboot, e.g. `init 6` which is the way we would otherwise safe reboot?

Answer (score 27):

- [`halt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/halt.8.html) instructs the hardware to [stop all CPU functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire), but leaves it in a powered-on state. This usually means someone has to reboot or shut the machine down manually by pressing the power button afterwards. The specific way to achieve this is architecture specific, but for instance the x86 instruction set provides the [`HLT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLT) instructions which halts the central processing unit (CPU) until the next external interrupt is fired.
- [`poweroff`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/halt.8.html), like `halt`, stops the CPU but also sends an [ACPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) hardware signal which will instruct the system to commence with a complete and immediate shutdown. This is roughly equivalent to pressing the power button on a typical desktop computer.

Both `halt` and `poweroff` are usually symbolic links to the `reboot` executable, which will usually invoke the [`shutdown`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/shutdown.8.html) tool with the appropriate arguments (`-h`, `-P` or `r`) depending on if `halt`, `poweroff` or `reboot` was used to invoke the tool. However, When the `--force` option is passed to `reboot`, or when in runlevel 0 or 6, `reboot` will invoke the [`reboot()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html) system call with an appropriate command code itself.

Comment: Thomas, thank you very much for explaining. I am interested to know what about doing a #init 0, there is not much differences right?

Comment: @Win.T Switching to runlevel 0 using e.g. `/sbin/init 0` or `/sbin/telinit 0` should be the same as halting the system, although the specific steps taken would depend on the init system in question, such as [System-V init](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/sysvinit), [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) or [systemd](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/systemd/). If you're running RHEL, you would be using systemd.

Comment: Note to self: every time someone complains about an arcane Win32 API call, show them reboot(2).

Comment: @immibis But reboot is purposely arcane. It requires the magic flags so that it is very difficult to do by accident.

Comment: @KevinCox That's the argument for requiring magic flags. It's not the argument for accepting 4 different values for magic2, nor for behaving differently inside a PID namespace, nor for lumping several barely-related operations (like setting reboot-on-Ctrl-Alt-Delete behaviour) into one function.

Answer (score 1):

`halt`, `poweroff` and `shutdown -h` are completely equivalent. In fact, halt and poweroff do nothing but call `shutdown -h`. From the halt/poweroff manpage:

> If halt or reboot is called when the system is not in runlevel 0 or 6, in other words when it's running normally, shutdown will be invoked instead (with the -h or -r flag). For more info see the shutdown(8) manpage.

Shutdown then proceeds to shut down the system by switching to runlevel 0.

Halt and poweroff (and reboot) perform a dual role; when executed in the process of shutting down (i.e., in runlevel 0 or 6), they perform the low-level operations required to physically stop, power off, or reboot the machine, as described in another answer.

Comment: Which version of RHEL are you using? There normally is a difference between halt and poweroff (although for a while it used not to be the case in many distributions, but that was a bug).