# Starting Debian without X

Tags: debian, x11, xdm

I am trying to start Debian without X, so I set `/etc/x11/default-display-manager` empty.

It works, but i get a

```
random:nonblocking pool is initialized
```

message.

Is there a better way to do it? Why I'm getting that message?

I'm using xdm.

Comment: Which Debian version do you have installed? Are you using `systemd`?

Comment: Googling for "random:nonblocking pool is initialized" I've found this : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303318 . Try `nomodeset` as a boot option and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: "random:nonblocking pool is initialized" is a normal boot up message... it's not an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210238/60986

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want `xdm` to start at boot, simply disable its systemd unit or initscript:

```
systemctl disable xdm
```

or

```
update-rc.d xdm disable
```

If you don't need `xdm` at all you should be able to uninstall it.