# Runlevel script

Tags: scripting, runlevel

I want to make a simple script so that the user can easy change the runlevels.
The script should prompt the user to choose the new runlevel, run the /sbin/init program and receive a confirmation message.

Any ideas ?

P.S if the runlevel is changed i want to receive a confirmation message. Help please

Comment: The official command for changing run levels is telinit

Comment: Bear in mind that you might be running [an operating system where run levels have been declared "obsolete"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132) and where [`telinit` is a backwards compatibility command that "should not be used anymore"](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/telinit.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try simply,

Create file named `myscript` with following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter Run level":
read rl;
sudo init $rl;
```

Where `echo` is used to print what to input, `read` is used to get the input and store into variable `rl` and  `sudo init $rl;` to execute command for changing run level.

For more **control**/verification over input, you can use loop such as `while` and `case`.

You've to give execution permission:`sudo chmod +x myscript` so that it can be executed.

Then you can run script like:

```
$ ./myscript
$ Enter Run level : 3
```

EDIT:

as @RuiFRibeiro [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250672/runlevel-script/250674#comment431655_250672), the command to change runlevel is `telinit`:

```
NAME
       telinit - change system runlevel

SYNOPSIS
       telinit [OPTION]...  RUNLEVEL

DESCRIPTION
       telinit may be used to change the system runlevel.
```

So, You should use `telinit` instead `init` in script.

---

And to check run level you can use `who -r` or `runlevel` command which output previous and current runlevel.

```
$ who -r | awk '{print $1,$2}'
run-level 3
$ runlevel
2 3
```

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I've also pointed that in answer. thanks