# Fedora systemctl isolate multi-user.target

Tags: fedora, systemd, vmware, runlevel

Distro : Fedora 24

Virtualisation : VMware pro

In a quest to learn about runlevels in Unix/Linux Systems and since i'm using Fedora with systemd , i use the following command to go from level 5 (with the GUI GNOME) to level 3, but instead of getting a command shell i get a black screen with nothing, am i misunderstunding something ? :

```
# systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

Black Screen :

[image: Black Screen]

My configuration :

[image]

Comment: [Forget about runlevels](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132).

Comment: Im a newbie, so i dont need to learn about them ? their is an alternative ? :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research , the solution is to change the Linux Terminal from tty1 to tty2 for example , the shortcut to do so is : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>  (if you use a VM , go in full screen mode before using the shortcut) , but now i have another problem, when i want to get to graphic mode i get "PolicyKit daemon disconnected from the bus" which apparently is a bug : [PolicyKit bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1205008)

More informations :

[Ubuntu Forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2330707)