# linux run levels: what is impact of running a httpd service on 35 and on 0123456

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd, runlevel

I know that,

```
run level=0  =>     Halt/Shuts down system
run level=1  =>     Single-User Mode
run level=2  =>     Multi-User Mode
run level=3  =>     Multi-User Mode with Networking
run level=4  =>     Undefined
run level=5  =>     level 3 + display managers
run level=6  =>     Reboot
```

what I am interested to know is,

> What is the difference in both the configurations for httpd service?
> (additional general description is fine)
>
> Is it a good practice to use all run levels for a particular service?
>
> and anything important that one should to know about?

Thank you

Comment: [Forget about run levels.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the httpd service will not distinguish between the different run levels, with the exception that it will only be started in some of the levels.

```
chkconfig --list httpd
```

should list which levels the the httpd service will be running under.

As to which levels to run under.  This really does not matter much since most machines spend 99.9% of their life at a single runlevel.

([Docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-services-chkconfig.html))

Comment: thank you. Is it a good practice to start a the service on all run-levels? Any issues with that?

Comment: No issue, except some run levels do not have the others services running the httpd needs.  But why?  What do you hope to accomplish by starting it at run levels you are not using?