# What is the practical difference between `systemctl start reboot.target` and `systemctl reboot`?

Tags: systemd, reboot

There are two documented differences between `start reboot.target` and `reboot`.  But `start reboot.target` is what is triggered by `ctrl-alt-del.target`.

Does it matter that `ctrl-alt-del.target` will omit `--job-mode=replace-irreversibly`?  In what situations will this cause different behaviour?   Why is it included by `systemctl reboot`?

```
man systemctl
```

> reboot [arg]
>
> Shut down and reboot the system. This is mostly equivalent to `start reboot.target --job-mode=replace-irreversibly`, but also prints a
>              wall message to all users.

```
man systemd.special
```

> ctrl-alt-del.target:
>              systemd starts this target whenever Control+Alt+Del is pressed on the console. Usually, this should be aliased (symlinked) to
>              reboot.target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When queuing a new job, this option controls how to deal with already queued jobs. It takes one of "fail", "replace", "replace-irreversibly", "isolate", "ignore-dependencies", "ignore-requirements" or "flush". Defaults to "replace", except when the isolate command is used which implies the "isolate" job mode.
>
> If "fail" is specified and a requested operation conflicts with a pending job (more specifically: causes an already pending start job to be reversed into a stop job or vice versa), cause the operation to fail.
>
> If "replace" (the default) is specified, any conflicting pending job will be replaced, as necessary.
>
> If "replace-irreversibly" is specified, operate like "replace", but also mark the new jobs as irreversible. This prevents future conflicting transactions from replacing these jobs (or even being enqueued while the irreversible jobs are still pending). Irreversible jobs can still be cancelled using the cancel command.

This suggests a practical effect.  Suppose you "hook units into the sleep state logic", using `sleep.target` to pull them in.  Your hook units do not have `DefaultDependencies=no`, so they depend on `sysinit.target`... and `Conflict` with `shutdown.target`.

If you run `systemctl start reboot.target` and then immediately `systemctl start suspend.target`, it seems that your hook unit will stop `shutdown.target`.  Now `systemd-reboot.service` has `Requires=shutdown.target`, so it should be stopped/cancelled as well.  (`umount.target` should not be cancelled).

I have verified a difference in behaviour along these lines and [reported it as a defect in the systemd issue tracker](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6471).

Answer (score 1):

From reading the source of the `reboot.target` file, we see that `ctrl-alt-del.target` is referenced with `Alias=`, meaning it's another name for the same command and will work the same way.

[Looking at the source code of systemctl.c](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/systemctl/systemctl.c#L3037), we also see that `systemctl reboot` will pass the `replace-irreversibly` option.

So it appears that all three variations of reboot commands you found work the same: `systemctl reboot`, `reboot.target` and `ctrl-alt-del.target`.

If you have a proposal for improving the documentation, you can modify the  [source XML files for the systemd documentation](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/tree/master/man) and submit a pull request.

Comment: Why would we want to look at the source of systemctl?  Of course it matches the documentation quoted.  Both tell us that `systemctl start reboot.target` will not automatically pass `--job-mode=replace-irreversibly`, and therefore will _not_ work exactly the same as `systemctl reboot`.

Comment: `start reboot.target` causes `reboot.service` to run, which in turn calls `ExecStart=/bin/systemctl --force reboot`, which as described above *does* pass the `--job-mode=replace-irreversibly` option, so they all work the same. You can search for the `reboot.target` and `reboot.service` files on yoru system and read them to confirm.

Comment: Nope!  Read the documentation for `--force`. `systemctl --force reboot` doesn't manipulate units, so there isn't a job mode to be concerned with.  It just runs `systemd-shutdown`.  Look at the systemctl code.  (although it goes through a `systemd` dbus method instead of launching directly, I haven't looked what the benefit is of that).  My question stands.  (Also, there is no `reboot.service` :-P).