# systemd "oneshot" service to trigger poweroff

Tags: systemd, reboot

Show a systemd `Type=oneshot` service which triggers a system power-off.  For example this could be used for `sigpwr.target`, to avoid the problem that `sigpwr.target` is not [started with the job mode `replace-irreversible`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381739/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-systemctl-start-reboot-target-and-sy).

<del>Ensure the oneshot service is not killed before it finishes, as this would cause a failure to be shown.</del>

1. Is there a possible ordering where systemd stops or kills your service before it has finished?  What effect will this have, if any?
2. Will your service work as well if it *is* started with the job mode `replace-irreversible`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# trigger-poweroff.service
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl --no-block poweroff
```

`DefaultDependencies=no` avoids an implicit `Conflicts=shutdown.target`.  This means it won't matter if the service is started with the job mode `replace-irreversible`.  It also avoids an implicit `Wants=sysinit.target`; this would be suboptimal e.g. if you wanted to start this service after transitioning to `emergency.target`.

`Before=shutdown.target` makes sure the service finishes before systemd-shutdown starts sending signals.  If nothing else, this makes the unit simpler to analyze for correctness.  We avoid a deadlock by making sure the service does not also wait for the poweroff to complete.

It wouldn't matter if `systemd-shutdown` killed the systemctl process with SIGTERM.  The process would simply terminate with status `WIFSIGNAL` and a `WTERMSIG` of `SIGTERM`.  Systemd treats this as a clean, successful exit.  See the definition of SuccessExitStatus in `man systemd.exec`.  However, if the kernel mysteriously didn't schedule this initial exit before the systemd `DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_USEC`, systemd-shutdown would then send the unblockable signal SIGKILL.  Systemd would not treat this as a successful exit.