# systemd - disable and reboot after oneshot is completed

Tags: systemd

I want to reboot the machine after `oneshot` script is completed and the current service should not be started on next reboot. I have create below systemd unit file

dummy.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Custom Unit File Automation
Wants=multi-user.target
After=multi-user.target
SuccessAction=reboot

[Service]
User=veeru
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "<command> <args>"
StandardOutput=/var/log/command_out.log
StandardError=/var/log/command_err.log
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/systemctl disable /etc/systemd/system/playbook_2.service"


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I was able to disable the service `systemctl`. But not able to reboot the machine, in the `status`, I see

```
Jun 28 01:45:55 hyddrogen systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/dummy.service:5] Unknown lvalue 'SuccessAction' in section 'Unit'
```

Is there any proper options to disable service and reboot machine. I can put `reboot` in `ExecStartPost`, but I don't want to do that

**UPDATE**

I got `SuccessAction` option from this [doc](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#SuccessAction=)

Comment: You got that error because "In user mode, only none, exit, and exit-force are allowed"

Comment: Right, now I see that in doc. Can you suggest any other options?

Comment: I don't have an Answer; I just wanted to point out why your one option wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I found a way to do this. Here is my unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=Custom Unit File Automation
After=default.target
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target

[Service]
User=veeru
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "<command> <args>"
StandardOutput=file:/var/log/command_out.log
StandardError=file:/var/log/command_err.log
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/systemctl disable /etc/systemd/system/dummy.service
ExecStop=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/reboot

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

From [systemd "oneshot" service to trigger poweroff](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382999/systemd-oneshot-service-to-trigger-poweroff) , I have added `DefaultDependencies=no` and `Before=shutdown.target`, slightly better way to stop daemon before reboot

Answer (score 0):

That solution seems a bit hacky.  I'm having trouble understanding why you would want a oneshot service that calls reboot, why not just use a script?

Anyhow, if you really wanted to do this as a systemd unit, you could simply have the oneshot touch a file, and then have a conditional that checks for the file.

Such as:

```
[Unit]
ConditionPathExists=/var/Custom_command.data
```