# "shutdown -r" works but "reboot" does not

Tags: centos, shutdown, reboot, hang

- Fresh install of Centos 7
- KDE
- kernel: 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64

After I do a `yum update` to update all of the packages, `reboot` no longer works. I tried to track the problem with no avail. For fun, I tried KDE's `Leave > Reboot` via the GUI. This worked successfully. I then tried `shutdown -h now` and that also worked flawlessly. Though, `reboot` hangs IMMEDIATELY after I hit [Enter], waits about 5-seconds, then goes into Kdump. I get a `/var/log/crash/[host]/vmcore-dmesg.txt` but have no idea how to interpret the kernel panic's or call traces.

Is there an easier way to find out what's happening and fix what's wrong with my `reboot` command?

Comment: To reboot CentOS, you can use `/usr/sbin/init 6`

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to reboot, is now

```
systemctl reboot
```

since [systemd](/questions/tagged/systemd) populate majority of linux distros

Comment: That does not answer the question asked.  Also, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132 .