# How do I shutdown, reboot and logout the system from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, shutdown, logout, reboot

I would like to do that using the command-line, because sometimes my computer freezes and I need to force a shutdown (I know it's not good to the hardware).
And: [What is the difference between Halt and Shutdown commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/what-is-the-difference-between-halt-and-shutdown-commands)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the commands [`shutdown`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown) and [`reboot`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/reboot) respectively. To log off from a terminal you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> or type `exit`.

Comment: or type `exit` instead of Ctrl+D ... or just execute shutdown/reboot via SSH `ssh root@brokenbox reboot`

Answer (score 10):

If you can still access a text mode console, or if you can log in remotely:

- You can use `ps` or other process listing tools and [kill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_%28command%29) to try killing some processes. A few programs will save your work (at least to a recovery file) if they receive a [`kill -HUP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) or [plain `kill`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTERM). They might not have time to do it if you go straight for rebooting.
- Run `sudo kill` followed by a process ID to kill a process that's running as root or some other user who is not you.
- Run `reboot` to reboot (e.g. `sudo reboot` if you use `sudo` to gain administrative access). Run `halt` to power the computer off. Both of these call [`shutdown`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown) with appropriate options.

If absolutely everything is hosed, but you have console access, you can use [magic SysRq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq) to at least flush all file changes to disk unmount filesystems cleanly. Press

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to send SIGT**E**RM to all processes (optional).
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to **s**ynchronize (flush) filesystem changes to disk.
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to forcefully **u**nmount (actually, remount read-only) all filesystems.
4. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to re**b**oot.

(Note: you'll sometimes see “REISUB”, but the R and I steps are useless.)

Comment: Just to make it easy to remeber, its BUSIER backwards.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a frozen X session, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> to get to a console. Log in and from there, execute `/sbin/shutdown`, `/sbin/reboot` or `/sbin/shutdown -r now`. Depending on permissions, you may need to prefix these commands with `sudo` or first `su` to become root.

You may also be able to kill the offending process. Run `ps aux` to list all processes and look for ones which are using a lot of CPU and/or memory (third and fourth columns). Use `kill <pid>`, where pid is the number in the second column of the `ps` output). If this doesn't kill the process, you may need to run `kill -9 <pid>` to forcefully kill it.

Comment: `ctrl+alt+f1` may not work on all systems (some have the X session there), but `ctrl+alt+f3` will on most, except for installation live systems maybe.

Answer (score 0):

If your BIOS is setup in a way where you have to press the power-button more than X seconds to actually turn off the machine, press the power-button once. This will give the acpi-signal for shutdown/halt/poweroff.