# Is halt the same as "shutdown -H" and poweroff the same as "shutdown -P"?

Tags: shutdown

I haven't found a clear answer to the differences between the two options to the command `shutdown`.

Is `halt` the same as `shutdown -H` and `poweroff` the same as `shutdown -P`?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/what-is-the-difference-between-halt-and-shutdown-commands

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's a bit historical.

`halt` was used before ACPI (which today will turn off the power for you)*. It would halt the system and then print a message to the effect of "it's ok to power off now". Back then there were physical on/off switches, rather than the combo ACPI controlled power button of modern computers.

`poweroff`, naturally will halt the system and then call ACPI power off.

* These days `halt` is smart enough to automatically call `poweroff` if ACPI is enabled. In fact, they are functionally equivalent now.

Comment: Interesting: on my laptop that runs Gentoo, `/sbin/poweroff` is a symlink to `/sbin/halt`.

Comment: Thanks, bahamat! I am talking about two options to the command `shutdown`. Is command `halt` the same as `shutdown -H`, and command `poweroff` the same as `shutdown -P`? @phunehehe too.

Comment: @phunehehe: Yeah, I was pretty sure they're the same now, but didn't bother to look.

Comment: @Tim: Yes, those flags are the same as calling the command. Like I said, it's pretty much a historical difference.

Comment: Back in the day, `halt` used to do just that.  No orderly shutdown, just stop what the machine was doing right then and there.  It was common to issue `sync;sync;sync;halt` to make sure all buffers had been written out to disk.

Answer (score 15):

They're not the same thing, just very closely related. In practice, unless you want to specify a particular time to shutdown or to force an immediate unclean reboot/halt/poweroff, it really doesn't matter whether you run `shutdown -h` or `halt`... or `shutdown -r` vs `reboot`. Things weren't so nicely convenient in the past, but this is the way it works now (a lot of the opportunities for ambiguity or user error have been removed/smoothed out).

`/sbin/shutdown` does a lot of "cleanup" stuff like notifying users, blocking new logins while the system is shutting down. It can also be told to shutdown the system at a certain time or in XX minutes - warning logged-in users every so often of the impending shutdown.

It also changes runlevel to `0` (`halt`/`poweroff`) or `6` (`reboot`) which triggers the system to stop the running services, unmount disks, etc in preparation for the actual halt, poweroff, or reboot.

When all that is done, it then calls `/sbin/halt`, `/sbin/reboot`, or `/sbin/poweroff` (`reboot` and `poweroff` are usually symlinks to `halt`, which interprets them as `halt -r` and `halt -P` respectively).

Note, however, that if `halt`/`reboot`/`poweroff` is called when the system is NOT in runlevel `0` or `6` then they will call `shutdown` to do its job unless the `-f` or `force` option is used.

(The details of how run-levels are interpreted may vary from distro to distro, but `0` and `6` are used as described here in Debian and Debian-derivatives like Ubuntu).

See the man pages for `shutdown` and `halt` for more info.

Finally, the distinction between `halt` and `poweroff` state is that `halt` does everything up to actually powering the machine off (on some kinds of hardware this means it drops into a ROM bootloader or similar. On most PC hardware it just halts), while `poweroff` completes that final step and switches off.  `reboot`, of course, gets to the halt state and then reboots the computer.

BTW, the default is typically to either `poweroff` or `reboot`, but you can use `-H` as an argument to `shutdown` to make it halt instead. This isn't very useful on PC-based linux boxes (but is useful on machines, like sparc boxes, that have a firmware boot monitor. It's possible it may become useful on newer machines with an EFI command line).

Comment: This is a highly Linux-centric answer to a non-operating-system-specific question.  Not all `shutdown` commands have the notion of run levels.  `shutdown` mostly _does not_ invoke `halt`/`reboot`/`poweroff`; ironically it is on a few _non-Linux_ systems where this received wisdom still remains true today.  And where the symbolic links point is not necessarily `halt`; not only that, in some toolsets they are not _symbolic_ links at all.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196471/5132 for more details.