# What's the difference between poweroff and halt?

Tags: linux

To turn off my system, I can use one of these three commands:

```
sudo halt
```

Or:

```
sudo poweroff
```

Or:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

What are the differences between these commands, or are they all just aliases of each other?

Comment: This question is marked as duplicate, but the "answers" just raise more questions - at least for those not intimate with the inner workings of Linux. On `Raspbian` which is still `init` based `reboot` and `poweroff` are links to `halt`. `shutdown` is different (the differences described in the answers). `Ubuntu MATE` for the Pi2 is `systemd` based and all 4 are links to `/bin/systemctl`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`halt` terminates all processes and shuts down the cpu.

`poweroff` is exactly like `halt`, but it also turns off the unit itself (lights and everything on a PC). It sends an ACPI command to the board, then to the PSU, to cut the power.

`shutdown` is like `poweroff`, but it also runs shutdown scripts which should stop things gracefully. Examples include giving programs a chance to close files, delete their lock files and unmount drives properly.

Sources:

https://serverfault.com/questions/191537/shutdown-what-is-difference-between-power-off-and-halt

http://osdir.com/ml/os.solaris.managers.summaries/2001-10/msg00027.html

A comment by [Peter White](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/40121/peter-white)

Comment: But which one to use if you want to shutdown and poweroff a system remotely gracefully, giving programs a chance to close files, delete their lock files and unmount drives properly?

Comment: I would use `shutdown --poweroff` for that.

Comment: This is out of date. See this answer for a more up to date answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196471/206286