# Why can't I find the -f option for shutdown command in man?

Tags: rhel, man, shutdown, reboot, fsck

I read on some linux blogs that to reboot without going through fsck you can use the following command:

```
shutdown -rf now
```

I read that the -f flag means "reboot fast".

However, I cannot find any references to this option in the man of my RHEL 6.5.

Comment: Where did you read `f` is fast reboot? Seeing the man page for `shutdown` it doesn't show any `-f` flag. https://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown It could be deprecated and removed

Comment: I found the reference in several links like this one for example : http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ushutdow.htm or this one : http://unixadminguide.blogspot.fr/2013/12/how-to-disable-fsck-on-reboot-in-linux.html

Comment: Maybe that flag was removed, do a `man shutdown` and you will see all the flags available. The post you link is from 2013, a long time ago.

Comment: I imagine this option is deprecated then. How can I check that it is a deprecated option?

Comment: I don't know how to see if it was deprecated but maybe looking to the RHEL/Linux/Unix changelog you can find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any reference to this flag in any of my running systems, but I have found one at linuxcommand.org:

http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/shutdown8.html

```
   -f     Skip fsck on reboot.
```

My guess is that it does not work with every boot loader, so it has been removed.

Comment: There's no need to guess.  The information is already on Stack Exchange.  Start at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196471/5132  and http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132

Comment: Nice and detailed links.