# What is the necessity of the commands `halt --poweroff` , `halt --reboot`, `poweroff --reboot` and `reboot --poweroff`?

Tags: terminal, reboot

In UNIX the following commands are present:

```
halt --poweroff     //does poweroff
halt --reboot       //does reboot
poweroff --reboot   //does reboot
reboot --poweroff   //does poweroff
```

However the following three simple commands do the same job

```
halt
poweroff
reboot
```

So what is the necessity of such commands

Comment: I think you forgot `shutdown -h now` and `shutdown -r now` as well.

Comment: Which Unix specifically?

Comment: I guess these commands apply in all flavors uniformly

Comment: It was (and is) also common to invoke one particular command under different names using links, and the same effect can usually be achieved using the original name and options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to our question is more or less: History!

Those are typically symlinks to the same binary. On systems using systemd often to `systemctl`, on an older system I just checked `reboot` and `poweroff` are symlinks to `halt`.

There are systems out there where `halt` and `poweroff` doesn't do the same thing, in that `halt` stops the OS, leaving the machine running with whatever environment the hardware offers, while `poweroff` does what it says and makes the machine stop consuming power. (It should be obvious that `reboot` is a third operation).

Comment: There is more on the history, where I comment on the embarrassing position that we are in nowadays, at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196471/5132 .