# Difference between reboot -p and reboot

Tags: rhel, boot, reboot

I understand that `-p` stands for power off.

The  man page says:

> **-p, --poweroff**
>
> ```
>        Power-off the machine, regardless of which one of the three
>        commands is invoked.
> ```

But exactly what does it do in reboot?

When tried both `reboot` and `reboot -p` in a RHEL 7 machine, I failed to find any appreciable difference.

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195898/ .

Comment: @JdeBP An excellent resource. And a must read. However, it does not answer my question.

Comment: Which is why it is a _question comment_ rather than an _answer_ and is talking about _related_ rather than _duplicate_ questions.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is wrong. As others have pointed out: `halt`, `reboot` and `poweroff` are all symlinked to `systemctl`. That program first looks at the name it was invoked from and sets the action it is going to take (one of halt, reboot or poweroff). It then parses its arguments one by one to see if any of them override the default. However, looking at the source code, a poweroff option can not override anything when the current action is reboot.

`reboot --halt --poweroff` will power off the machine though, because when systemctl parses the final argument the current action is set to halt (from the previous argument).

Comment: There is more on the embarrassing position that we are in nowadays with this (c.f. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372732/), at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196471/5132 .