# Systemd: how to shut down without actually shutting down

Tags: systemd, embedded, shutdown

I'm setting up an embedded device running Debian Jessie to shut down when a UPS experiences a power failure. Unfortunately, the device's bootloader restarts the OS whenever it quits, so shutdown/halt commands are equivalent to restart.

My main concern is protecting the data on the attached hard disks. I think my best option is to kill as many tasks as possible and then wait for the power to cut. `systemctl isolate emergency.target` seems close to what I want, except it leaves the disks mounted. Is there a way to basically get Systemd to `final.target` without an actual shutdown/halt command?

Comment: A related question is https://superuser.com/questions/900109/ .

Answer (score 2):

`systemctl halt` might do the trick. From the manual:

```
halt
    Shut down and halt the system. This is mostly equivalent to
    systemctl start halt.target --job-mode=replace-irreversibly
    --no-block, but also prints a wall message to all users. This
    command is asynchronous; it will return after the halt operation is
    enqueued, without waiting for it to complete. Note that this
    operation will simply halt the OS kernel after shutting down,
    leaving the hardware powered on. Use systemctl poweroff for
    powering off the system (see below).
```

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195898/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/ for more on this.

Comment: Alas, no joy. As JdeBP's wonderfully in depth answer to the first question they links above says, `systemctl halt` and `shutdown -H now` are equivalent in systemd. All these commands do halt the OS kernel, but that's when the bootloader  starts the system again! I need a way to shut everything else down but leave a minimal kernel running.

Comment: This is the right answer for the general question of how to halt a machine or VM running systemd. In OP's case, they have a watchdog-like system that impedes this, but I thought it would be good to mention that it is correct for the general case. (Which is what I came here for.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this isn't just a problem with some sort of watchdog device, you can try hijacking the `kexec` target for systemd. That's ordinarily used for loading a kdump kernel to dump memory, but you can really set up that target to do anything.

I created a systemd unit called `kexec-sleep` and put it into `/etc/systemd/system/kexec-sleep.service` (I'm not sure if these `Requires`/`After`/`Before` lines are quite right, but they worked for me in a virtual machine):

```
[Unit]
Description=Sleep forever at kexec
DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=umount.target
After=umount.target
Before=final.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/kexec-sleep
KillMode=none

[Install]
WantedBy=kexec.target
```

That will call `/sbin/kexec-sleep`, which is just a shell script (shown below). It attempts to remount the root filesystem read-only, so it should stay in a clean state until the device powers down. I have some `sleep`s in there that are probably longer than what you need, plus a prompt at the end that will let you reboot without needing to pull the power cord.

```
#!/bin/sh

stty sane < /dev/console       # enable automatic CRLF output on console
exec < /dev/console > /dev/console 2>&1  # redirect stdio to/from console
echo "Sleeping several seconds for processes to terminate..."
sleep 10
# kill some expected processes
killall dhclient
# sleep again...
sleep 5
echo "Processes still running:"
/bin/ps --ppid 2 -p 2 --deselect    # list non-kernel processes
echo "Attempting to remount root filesystem read-only..."
sync; sync; sync
mount -o remount,ro /
grep /dev/sda /proc/mounts
while true; do
    echo "System paused. Type 'reboot' to reboot"
    read -p '> ' entry
    if [ "$entry" = "reboot" ]; then
        /sbin/reboot -f
    fi
done
```

After creating those files, run `chmod +x /sbin/kexec-sleep` and `systemctl enable kexec-sleep`.

To trigger this instead of a normal shutdown, run `systemctl kexec`.

Comment: This is awesome, and seems really close to working. When I run `systemctl kexec`, it culminates with 3 lines from `systemd-shutdown[1]`: `Rebooting with kexec.` / `kexec failed with error code 1.` / `Rebooting.` -- I don't see the expected echo outputs, so I'm not sure where the failure is.

Comment: It fails this way even if /sbin/kexec-sleep only contains `exit 0`...