# Shutdown does not power off. Why?

Tags: shutdown

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I am having problems shutting down and restarting the computer.  I trigger a shutdown, the computer eventually says

```
Reached target shutdown
```

and halts.  It does not power off.

So, what problem may I have and what should I do to solve it?

Comment: Well, it says `Reached target shutdown` and halts!

Comment: Is that not a successful shutdown?!?

Comment: I don't think so since my system won't power off!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the details you added in the comments. Also tell us something about your hardware. Is this a laptop? A desktop? Are you connected to a network? Are you mounting any remote shares from the network?

Comment: You still haven't [followed the standard litany](http://jdebp.info./FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html) and told the world _what you did_ to trigger the shutdown.  For all we know, shutting down to halt is exactly what you told the computer to do.

Comment: An example of what we need to help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/632591/system-does-not-power-off-on-poweroff-just-halts

Answer (score 3):

As @JdeBP said, you have not clarified what exactly you did. However, the answer to your questions may lie in the man page:

```
man shutdown
```

Which tells us,

```
shutdown may be used to halt, power-off or reboot the machine.
```

So for your questions,

> I am having problems shutting down and restarting the computer
>
> It does not power off

to reboot, you should run (if you didn't already),

```
shutdown -r
```

and if you're trying to power off,

```
shutdown -P
```

Also, have a look at this question which mentions the exact thing you do: https://askubuntu.com/questions/632591/system-does-not-power-off-on-poweroff-just-halts

And this question talks more about the commands `halt` and `shutdown`:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/73696/what-is-the-proper-terminal-way-to-shutdown

Comment: Enjoy https://superuser.com/a/900205/38062 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132 , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196471/5132 as well.