# On OSes with SysvInit, are `reboot` and `halt` symlinks to some executables?

Tags: init, sysvinit

On  OSes with Systemd, `reboot` and `halt` are symlinks to `systemctl`.

On OSes with SysvInit, what are `reboot` and `halt`  symlinks to? Is it `telinit`? Or are they themselves executable files, not symlinks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Debian Jessie (for example), `reboot` may come from `sysvinit-core` ( https://packages.debian.org/jessie/sysvinit-core )

Downloading the file ( https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/sysvinit-core/download )

```
$ mkdir X
$ cd X
$ ar x ../sysvinit-core_2.88dsf-59_amd64.deb
$ xz -dc < data.tar.xz | tar tvf - | egrep 'reboot|halt'
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     18776 2015-04-06 14:44 ./sbin/halt
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1753 2015-04-06 14:44 ./usr/share/man/man8/halt.8.gz
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2015-04-06 14:44 ./sbin/poweroff -> halt
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2015-04-06 14:44 ./sbin/reboot -> halt
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2015-04-06 14:44 ./usr/share/man/man8/reboot.8.gz -> halt.8.gz
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2015-04-06 14:44 ./usr/share/man/man8/poweroff.8.gz -> halt.8.gz
```

So we can see that `halt` is a separate program, and `poweroff` and `reboot` are symlinks to that.

Comment: There's more at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196471/5132 .