# Debian 9 halt does not really power off in new versions - why?

Tags: debian, halt

**IMPORTANT:**
**I am able to restore halt old behavior if I do:**

```
apt install sysvinit-core
```

**Plus:** Old **Red Hat** based versions are able to power off with halt too.

I am trying to understand why in Debian 9 you should not use halt to turn off your computer anymore. That behavior are removed from systemd.  I am a bit scary, but I think there must be a good logical reason.

Are other unixes or unix-like with this same behavior or are Linux turning into something different?

Now if you want to turn off the machine after the system shutdown you should use poweroff instead of halt...

Somebody know how this command are interpreted in other Unix-Like?

That is not a duplicated, because, debian 7 can power off with halt for example.

Comment: Plain `halt` powers off a macOS system, but not an OpenBSD system. `halt` is not a POSIX utility, nor is `poweroff` or `shutdown` or any similar utility.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini does this help? [What is the difference between these commands for bringing down a Linux server?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/195898)

Comment: @DopeGhoti I don't think this is a dupe. The OP wants to know _why_ this change happened, not what the difference between `halt` and `shutdown` may be.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I am trying to understand why this change happened. Thank you.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini did you read the link I gave in my previous comment? That seems to explain that the `shutdown` command simply doesn't exist anymore. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes it answers partially thank you. But poweroff still turns system off, is just halt that is not powering off at end anymore it just put system down but does not make the computer to turn off. Strange, but true, why dont keep it normal for the compatibility, why this different behavior for halt, and not for poweroff links.

Comment: `halt` allows for the system to be halted with diagnostic kernel messages still visible on the console on some systems; this is the reason for a distinction between `halt` and `poweroff` to exist at all.

Comment: @DopeGhoti right, but why if i install sysvinit-core halt start to turn off the computer.

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you for the informational example with other unixes, very usefully. SunOS Release 4 looks like to uses halt as the official shutdown command, replace by shutdown in version 5, and them halt becomes equivalent to halt -f (that will immediately shutdown). Maybe the old bsds can have different behaviors too...

Comment: Who downvoted please explain why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Debian

When using SysVinit in Debian(esque) systems, `/etc/defaults/halt` includes a variable that defines whether the system will run halt or poweroff at the end of transition to runlevel 0. The default setting is `HALT=poweroff`.

Before SysVinit 2.74 you were not supposed to run `halt` directly, and starting from that version, the SysVinit `halt` command will just call `shutdown -h` unless the current runlevel is 0 or 6. This is documented in `halt(8)` man page. At the end of transition to runlevel 0 the runlevel scripts will run `$HALT`, which is equal to `poweroff` by default.

### RHEL/CentOS

RHEL/CentOS 5 was the last version to use SysVinit: version 6 used `upstart` and version 7 uses `systemd`. In RHEL 5.11, the last script to run when transitioning to runlevel 0 is `/etc/init.d/halt`, and its last lines are:

```
[ "$INIT_HALT" != "HALT" ] && HALTARGS="$HALTARGS -p"

exec $command $HALTARGS
```

Since the same script is also run at the end of transition to runlevel 6 (reboot), the actual command to run is defined by the variable `$command`, and it will be either `/sbin/halt` or `/sbin/reboot`. According to the value of the `$INIT_HALT` variable, the script will decide whether or not add the `-p` option. That variable is set by `/sbin/shutdown`. The RHEL 5.11 `shutdown(8)` man page says:

> HALT OR POWEROFF
>
> The -H option just sets the init environment variable INIT_HALT to HALT,  and the -P option just sets that variable to POWEROFF. The shutdown script that calls halt(8) as  the last thing in the shutdown sequence should check these environment variables and call halt(8) with the right options for these options to actually have any effect.
>   Debian 3.1 (sarge) supports this.

(Yes, the RHEL 5.11 man page mentions Debian 3.1! I guess someone at RedHat porting patches from various sources to RHEL missed one reference...)

It looks like RedHat has decided to code the above-mentioned test in the `/etc/init.d/halt` script in such a way that switching off the power (using `/sbin/halt -p` at the end of shutdown) is the default halt action: the only way to achieve halt without poweroff is to use the upper-case `-H` option of the `shutdown` command to explicitly request it, e.g. `shutdown -hH now`

But again, the default powerdown is triggered by the runlevel scripts customized by the Linux distribution, so it's not really a feature of the SysVinit `halt` command.

### Historical note

Old SysVinit-using systems (both Linux and non) used to have several commands that were not intended to be used directly, but only as part of the appropriate shutdown/reboot scripts. Before SysVinit 2.74, the `/sbin/halt` command with no options would have done the same as `halt -f` of modern SysVinit does, i.e. a brutal, immediate kernel shutdown without stopping any services or unmounting filesystems.

For the same reason, being used to the Linux `killall` command can be dangerous on other Unixes. Its man page even has this ominous warning:

> Be warned that typing killall name may not have the desired effect on non-Linux systems, especially when done by a privileged user.

This is because the classic SystemV `killall` was one of those commands designed to be used only as part of a shutdown script. In Linux distributions with SysVinit, the classic version of the command may be found as `killall5`. It literally kills **all** processes except kernel threads and processes in its own session: its intended use is in a shutdown script after shutting down all services, just before unmounting the local filesystems, to kill of any other processes that might delay or prevent the unmounting.

(How I know this, you ask? Well, I once made the mistake of running `killall <something>` as root on a Solaris 2.6 system. A very effective learning experience.)

Comment: Yes that is what I am expecting! Very nice informations! Thank you a lot, specially about the notes about Red Hat doing the same behavior in older versions!

Comment: To solve all this problems and others, I just migrated to devuan, I am so happy with this system that I cannot explain.

Answer (score 3):

## This question is predicated upon multiple falsehoods.

One did not use `halt` to turn off one's computer, and this has not changed with systemd.

`halt` a.k.a. `haltsys` shuts down and halts.  `poweroff` is a newer command that shuts down and powers off.  (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196471/5132 explains the subtleties of this which I am going to gloss over here, since the question is only about Linux operating systems.  This answer focuses on just the AT&T System 5 UNIX side of the universe.)

As I explained at https://superuser.com/a/900205/38062, computers are not necessarily *able* to power off under software control.  The action of the `haltsys` and `halt` command has conventionally been to shutdown and halt the machine, the next action being the operator using a physical reset button or power switch.

`halt` gained a `-p`/`--poweroff` option to make it equivalent to `poweroff`, but this is symptomatic of a general growth of overlapping and self-contradictory options to these commands.  Witness [the manual page for the Upstart `halt` command in Debian 7](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/upstart/halt.8.en.html).  There's `halt --poweroff` there.  [The manual page for the van Smoorenburg `halt` command in Debian 7](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/sysvinit-core/halt.8.en.html) similarly has `halt -p`.

But this *is not* something that has changed with systemd.  systemd provides the same.  The [systemd `halt` command](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/halt.html) *also* has `--poweroff`.  It furthermore has `--reboot` and (for good measure) `--halt` options.

I had to do the same with [the `halt`/`haltsys` command in the nosh toolset](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/haltsys.xml), for compatibility.

You may *erroneously think* that plain old `halt` powered off your computer.  But that was unequivocally wrong for Upstart, and *only* true for the van Smoorenburg toolset *if you happened to hit a bug*.

The bug, which has only this year finally been fixed, was that the van Smoorenburg `halt` command would simply ignore the presence or absence of the `-p` option and instead decide whether to halt or power off according to the value of a setting in `/etc/default/halt`.  If you happened to have that setting set to power off, then `halt` would always power off, even if no `-p` option were supplied.  Conversely, if you happened to have that setting set to halt, then `halt` would always halt, even if a `-p` option were supplied.

But *this was a bug*, not the documented nor intended behaviour, not the behaviour of every `halt` command that was available on Debian, and not the conventional behaviour of the `halt` command in general.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018-12-07). *[Bug#586709: closed by Thomas Goirand](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=586709#94)*.  Debian bug #586709.
- Jessie Smith (2019-03-08). *[initscripts: command `halt` unintended changed behaviour](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=743555#25)*.  Debian bug #743555.

Comment: A falsehood that running apt install sysvinit-core turned true! Why? I just installed sysvinit, and at end halt says "Will now halt"  exactly in that moment the machine powered off, how could this be a falsehood, it looks like the developer of sysvinit still has this falsehood! and plus that halt -f turns off the machine immediately.

Comment: When using SysVinit in Debian(esque) systems, `/etc/defaults/halt` includes a variable that defines whether the system will run `halt` or `poweroff` at the end of transition to runlevel 0. The default setting is `HALT=poweroff`. Before SysVinit 2.74 you were not supposed to run `halt` directly, and starting from that version, the SysVinit `halt` command will just call `shutdown -h` unless the current runlevel is 0 or 6. This is documented in `halt(8)` man page. At the end of transition to runlevel 0 the runlevel scripts will run `$HALT`, which is equal to `poweroff` by default.

Comment: @telcoM Thank you very much for this! That is enough for me, if you put that as a answer I will mark it as the correct answer. (Note one thing (not very important), CentOS seems to have the same behavior in my old servers). Can you post this as a answer please?