# Ability to halt/reboot server as user

Tags: non-root-user, aws, amazon-ec2, halt

I need to ability to halt an aws EC2 server as user. I found https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-allow-users-to-shutdown-server.html but due to the fact that I need this feature on an aws EC2 instance, I don't have a static hostname, so I tried:

`ubuntu    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL=/sbin/halt /sbin/reboot`

but  that got me:

```
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 21 <<<
What now?     
Options are:
  (e)dit sudoers file again
  e(x)it without saving changes to sudoers file
  (Q)uit and save changes to sudoers file (DANGER!)
```

how can I solve this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/reboot-instances.html), as a user you can do (on the instance itself):

`aws ec2 reboot-instances --instance-ids $(curl -s http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id)`

See this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625644/how-to-get-the-instance-id-from-within-an-ec2-instance) on getting the EC2 ID from within the instance itself.

If you want to test to see if you have the required permissions before running, try including the `--dry-run` flag:

> --dry-run | --no-dry-run (boolean)
>
> Checks whether you have the required permissions for the action, without actually making the request, and provides an error response. If you have the required permissions, the error response is DryRunOperation . Otherwise, it is UnauthorizedOperation .

For context, see this [discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/what-is-the-difference-between-halt-and-shutdown-commands) on the difference between `halt`, `shutdown`, `reboot`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for:

```
ubuntu ALL=/sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot
```

This is identical to:

```
ubuntu ALL=(ALL:ALL) /sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot
```

Generally, you should always use `visudo` to edit your `sudoers` configuration, because it performs a syntax check on the file before placing it in the final location.

See the `sudoers(5)` man page for complete documentation, including a long list of documented examples.

---

If your question is "how do I recover from this situation", if you are not able to log in directly as `root`, then your best option is probably to delete the EC2 instance and create a new one.